# problum to get woocommerce product by category in REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

hello i am using REST API of woocommerce REST API ,
i want to get product by category . when i pass this url i got all product .

```
  https://www.ezdarshan.com/wc-api/v2/products/?consumer_key=ck_dbf0f35e37dc0xxxxxxxxxxxb31d2&consumer_secret=cs_ea299e9b86xxxxxxxxxxxxxxf785a9f77ec7
```

But when i use filter like this :  ?category=56,37

Again  i got all product but i want only product which related to these  category

i Follow this docs : https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-products

Some on help me

Comment: Kindly: What version for [**WooCommerce Rest API**](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)?… There is 4 possible versions… Please update your question with much more details as you can, to have a chance to get helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just resolved similar issue. Use slug instead of id / name. It worked for me.

```
https://yourwebsite.com/api/user/proxy/products/?filter[category]=<SLUG OF CATAGORY>
```

Correct: (note the trailing slash is removed)

```
 https://yourwebsite.com/api/user/proxy/products?filter[category]=<SLUG OF CATAGORY>
```

Comment: are you sure this is woocommerce api?  can you reference to the docs?

Answer (score 0):

This might be little late to answer but might be helpful for others

According to the new wordpress REST API version this worked for me

https://www.xxxx.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=categoryid